# Using Wget to download webpage with all supporting css/js/img files

Tags: wget

I've searched a lot how to achieve this but no avail. I want to download only 1 page from a website but also download all css/js/img files in parallel. I've tried the following command but it doesn't work as expected:

```
wget -k -np -p --adjust-extension http://example.com
```

Any idea how to do this?

I want the following:

```
-FOLDER

--index.html

---assets_folder
---- style.css
---- script.js
---- IMAGES_FOLDER_WITH_ALL_NEEDED_IMAGES_TO_DISPLAY_THE_PAGE
```

but with all assets even the CDNs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `wget -k -np -p -H --adjust-extension http://example.com`?

The `-H` (or `--span-hosts`) flag allows to retrieve assets from third-party hosts (which the CDNs are).

Answer (score 0):

`wget` is not suitable for this task as it has limited capability to parse the  URL you are passing to it.

While `wget` might be able to pull some stylesheets and maybe scripts it is unable to *render* the page so it has no way of building an interpreted version of the HTML markup with all the resources — this is a task that only a browser is able to do properly and this is the reason why even web spiders like googlebot and others use a full-blown rending engine such as webkit (the core library behind brave/chome/chromium/opera/edge/etc).

`wget` is great for old-school static pages, but with gmail-style web apps, social networks and anything heave on frontend it will be mostly useless.

For modern web pages with dynamic content that you'll get better results using browser extensions, such WebScrapBook (firefox & chrome), Save Page WE (firefox) and the like.